# What does "rev2" stand for?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Today I read a [paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/47693211_TradeProd_The_CEPII_Trade_Production_and_Bilateral_Protection_Database_Explanatory_Notes) and I saw the phrase "ISIC rev2 3-digit industry level". I am wondering what "rev2" stands for, I did a search but cannot find any [explanation](https://ilostat.ilo.org/resources/concepts-and-definitions/classification-economic-activities/) so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stands for "second revision".

These standards are changed (revised) from time to time. This designation tells the reader which version is being referred to.

See https://unstats.un.org/unsd/classifications/Family/Detail/8 . There you can see that that Rev 2 is out of date and you should use Rev 4.

Comment: So, "rev" here is just the edition of the industry classification, the bottom line of this phrase is "ISIC 3-digit industry level", am I correct?

Comment: Yes. That's what it says.